# QR Code Generator API with Lumen

Tags: php, api, laravel, qr-code, lumen

I'm developing an API to generate QR Codes with Lumen and Endroid/QrCode package.

How do I send a QR Code through an HTTP response so that I don't have to save the QR Code on my server?

I can do it on a single index.php file, but if I do it on Lumen framework (or Slim as well) I just get characters printed on the page.

Separate index.php:

```
$qr_code = new QRCode();
$qr_code
    ->setText("Sample Text")
    ->setSize(300)
    ->setPadding(10)
    ->setErrorCorrection('high')
    ->render();
```

works great!

Using Lumen i'm doing this:

```
$app->get('/qrcodes',function () use ($app) {
    $qr_code = new QrCode();
    $code = $qr_code->setText("Sample Text")
        ->setSize(300)
        ->setPadding(10)
        ->setErrorCorrection('high');

    return response($code->render());
});
```

and it doesn't work.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `QRCode::render()` method doesn't actually return the QR code string; it returns the QR object. Internally, the `render` method is calling the native PHP `imagepng()` function, which immediately streams the QR image to the browser, and then it returns `$this`.

There are two things you can try.

First, you can try just treating this route like you did your plain index file (though, I'm adding a call to `header()`):

```
$app->get('/qrcodes',function () use ($app) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    $qr_code = new QrCode();
    $qr_code->setText("Sample Text")
        ->setSize(300)
        ->setPadding(10)
        ->setErrorCorrection('high')
        ->render();
});
```

Another option you have is to capture the output in a buffer, and pass that to your `response()` method:

```
$app->get('/qrcodes',function () use ($app) {

    // start output buffering
    ob_start();

    $qr_code = new QrCode();
    $qr_code->setText("Sample Text")
        ->setSize(300)
        ->setPadding(10)
        ->setErrorCorrection('high')
        ->render();

    // get the output since last ob_start, and close the output buffer
    $qr_output = ob_get_clean();

    // pass the qr output to the response, set status to 200, and add the image header
    return response($qr_output, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/png']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but today i've faced the same problem. For the rendering of the QR in a lumen's view i use this:

```
                            $data['base64Qr']=$qrCode
                            ->setText("sample text")
                            ->setSize(300)
                            ->setPadding(10)
                            ->setErrorCorrection('high')
                            ->setForegroundColor(array('r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0))
                            ->setBackgroundColor(array('r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0))
                            ->setLabel('sample label')
                            ->setLabelFontSize(16)
                            ->getDataUri();
return view('view',$data);
```

This code return the Base64 string that i have inserted in a simple image

```
<img src="{{ $base64Qr }}">
```

Hope this will help anyone encounter this problem.